# Запрос в бд вместе со связями | Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Как в Laravel сделать запрос на получение записи вместе со связью? Допустим, есть таблица:

```
ChapterTable
________________________________
id | title | volume | created_at
1  | прив  | 1      | 0000:00...
2  | п112  | 1      | 0000:00...
3  | 3234  | 2      | 0000:00...

VolumeTable
________________________________
id | title | created_at
1  | том 1 | 0000:00...
2  | том 2 | 0000:00...
3  | том 3 | 0000:00...
```

Как мне получить из таблицы **chapterTable** строку с id = 1, и volume "том 1", вместо "1"??

```
SQL RESULT
________________________________
id | title | volume | created_at
1  | прив  | Том 1  | 0000:00...
```

Связи между **chapterTable.volume** и **volumeTable.id** уже прописаны.

```
Keyname                 Type     Unique Packed  Column  Cardinality  Collation  Null
____________________________________________________________________________________
chapters_volume_foreign |BTREEЭ  |No    |No     |volume |2          |A         |No
```

Comment: Простите, но возникает 2 вопроса: 1) вы заглядывали в документацию фреймворка - в eloquent relations https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships ? 2) Что конкретно у Вас не получается(какая из связей у Вас не работает)?

Comment: Читал, но мало что понял. Я добавил в модель Chapter функцию volume() { $this->hasOne(Volume::class) }, а в Volume функцию chapter(){$this->belongsTo(Chapter::class);}, но так и не понял, как этим пользоваться.

Comment: есть прекрасные бесплатные курсы по laravel от разработчиков. даже с субтитрами русскими.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему. Надо было в модель Chapter добавить фукнцию:

```
public function volume_info(){
    return $this->hasOne(Volume::class, 'id' <-- связанное поле у VolumeTable, 'volume' <-- связанное поле у текущей таблицы);
}
```

Ранее эта же функция называлась volume(), из-за чего при вызове:

```
$chapters = Chapter::where('book', $book)->orderByDesc('created_at')->limit(25)->get();

foreach ($chapters as $chapter) {
   dd($chapter->volume);
}
```

Я получал id volume, вместо объекта.